stty command does not change the baud rate
I am trying to use a Honeywell 1911i Barcode Scanner through a serial port on Ubuntu 22.04 machine.
I am having an issue where attempting to set the baud rate of the serial port via stty command does not work.
I perform:
sudo stty -F /dev/ttyS6 115200

Then the output of sudo stty /dev/ttyS6 gives:
speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
min = 1; time = 0;
-brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke

I cannot get the baud rate to change and stay changed.
The scanner is set to 115200, as well as in minicom. The code that processes the results of the scanner also opens the port with 115200.
EDIT: Upon further testing, it appears to be my software launching that is resetting the baud rate of the serial port to 9600, though I am unsure how that is possible so any insight is still appreciated.
CODE:

    type SerialScanner struct {

    //Scanner Options
    PortName  string
    PortList  []string
    PortOpen  bool
    baud      int
    bufferLen int

    portActive bool

    //Port for Server
    port string

    //Channels for GoRoutine Interaction
    readCh chan []byte
    quitCh chan bool
    ExitCh chan bool
}

func NewSerialScanner(port string) *SerialScanner {
    scanner := SerialScanner{
        PortName:       "",
        PortList:       []string{},
        baud:           115200,
        bufferLen:      128,
        port:           port,
        portActive:     true,
        readCh:         make(chan []byte),
        quitCh:         make(chan bool),
        ExitCh:         make(chan bool),
    }
    scanner.LoadState() // This just reads some information I have stored in a file.
    if scanner.PortName != "" {
        scanner.OpenPort()
    }
    return &scanner
}

func (scanner *SerialScanner) OpenPort() error {
    scanner.SavePort(scanner.PortName) // This saves the port being used in a file. User can switch between serial ports.
    go scanner.StartReading()
    return nil
}

func (scanner *SerialScanner) StartReading() error {
    var err error

    mode := &serial.Mode{BaudRate: scanner.baud, Parity: serial.NoParity, DataBits: 8, StopBits: serial.OneStopBit}
    port, err := scanner.openPort(mode)
    if logger.HandleError(err, fmt.Sprintf("Failed to open serial port %s", scanner.PortName)) != nil {
        return err
    }

    scanner.PortOpen = true

    logger.PrintLogInfo(fmt.Sprintf("Opened serial port %s", scanner.PortName))
    go scanner.MoniterHoneywellScannerConnection(&port)
    reader := bufio.NewReader(port)
    go scanner.read(reader)
    for {
        select {
        case buf := <-scanner.readCh:
            scanner.portActive = true
            _ = scanner.publish(buf)
            go scanner.read(reader)
        case <-scanner.quitCh:
            err = port.Close()
            if logger.HandleError(err, fmt.Sprintf("Failed to close serial port %s", scanner.PortName)) != nil {
                return err
            }
            scanner.PortOpen = false
            logger.PrintLogInfo(fmt.Sprintf("Closed serial port %s", scanner.PortName))
            return nil
        case <-time.After(60 * time.Second):
            scanner.portActive = false
        }
    }
}

func (scanner *SerialScanner) MoniterHoneywellScannerConnection(port *serial.Port) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-scanner.ExitCh:
            return
        case <-time.After(60 * time.Second):
            fmt.Println("Testing Serial Port Connection")
            _, err := (*port).Write([]byte("232bad?.\r\n"))
            if err != nil {
                logger.PrintLogError("Failed to write to serial port")
            }
        }
    }
}

func (scanner *SerialScanner) StopReading() {
    if scanner.PortOpen {
        scanner.quitCh <- true
    }
}

func (scanner *SerialScanner) read(reader *bufio.Reader) {
    buf := make([]byte, scanner.bufferLen)
    //Read blocks until at least one byte is sent or the port is closed
    n, err := reader.Read(buf)
    _ = logger.HandleError(err, fmt.Sprintf("Failed to read from serial port %s", scanner.PortName))

    if scanner.PortOpen {
        scanner.readCh <- buf[:n]
    }
}


What software are you using?

@vidarlo An application I created using Golang, to read scans sent to the serial port and process them. I use a library: link This simply opens the serial port and creates a goroutine the reads from the port.

Can you add relevant code to the question?

@vidarlo edited question with relevant code

Thanks. I have a feeling this may be a better fit at StackExchange, but it's not off topic here either...
